# build gradle over network resource

Tags: android, developer-tools, android-studio-3.6

there is no option to build gradle over network in V-3.6.4 there is no checkbox to disable offline build.
also there is no commmand to disable offline build .
please help me to come out from this issue

===============================

## Exception i got

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4.
>        Required by:
>            project :
>   No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4 available for offline mode.
>   No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4 available for offline mode.
>   Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3.
>        Required by:
>            project :
>   No cached version of com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3 available for offline mode.
>   No cached version of com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3 available for offline mode.

Comment: Please give more information/specifics on the issue as well as troubleshooting steps which you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable Gradle offline mode in android studio v 3.6.4

**Here are the steps:**

step1: goto **View> Tool windows> Gradle**

[image: Step1]

Step 2: Now the gradle panel opens up there you will see toggle button that enables and disables the gradle offline mode

[image: Step2]

Might this solve your problem :)